# Sprig "View Less" Button

Tags: plugin-sprig

I'm trying to build off the "Load More" button, and essentially "Load Less" by reverting back to the initial state. The code below resets it back to 0 and just starts load from the first item again, instead of resetting back to just displaying 1. I'm a bit stuck on how to work it other than just `visibility:hidden` on the divs that have loaded in.

```
{# Sets a default value if not defined by the `s-val:*` attribute on the button #}
{% set offset = offset ?? 0 %}
{% set entry = craft.entries.id(entryId).one() %}
{% set totalImages = entry.supplierImages.count() %}
{% set imagesQuery = entry.supplierImages.offset(offset).limit(limit) %}
{% set supplierImages = imagesQuery.all() %}

          {% for image in supplierImages %}
                <div class="col">
                  <div class="card bg-blue border-0 h-100 rounded-0 position-relative overflow-hidden">
                    <a href="{{ image.getUrl('largeImage') }}" data-lightbox="{{ entry.title }}" data-title="{{ image.title }}">
                      <img src="{{ image.getUrl('gridImage') }}" class="card-img-top rounded-0" height="250" alt="{{ image.title }}">
                    </a>
                    <div class="card-hover-caption bg-blue text-white position-absolute p-3 text-center">
                        <h6 class="mb-0">{{ image.title }}</h6>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
          {% endfor %}

{% set isAllDisplayed = totalImages <= offset + supplierImages|length %}
{% set buttonText = isAllDisplayed ? "Show Less" : "Load More" %}
{% set newOffset = isAllDisplayed ? 0 : (offset + limit) %}

{# Load More / Show Less Button #}
<button class="btn btn-md bg-transparent text-blue border-0 d-block m-auto my-4" 
        sprig 
        s-val:offset="{{ newOffset }}" 
        s-val:reset="{{ isAllDisplayed ? 'true' : 'false' }}"
        s-target="this" 
        s-swap="outerHTML">
    {{ buttonText }}
</button>
```

Comment: There’s no question here. If you can ask a specific question about a more generic piece of code, then I’d be happy to help.